# How to insert multiple small files ( <16 MB) in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I have a folder with 20 small files of different file types (.jpg, .bmp, .txt, .docx , .xlsx etc). All these file are between 100 KB to 10 MB in size.

How can I insert all these 20 files in one go in mongodb database?

Is there any other option other than GridFS to insert files as documents in MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize them as Base64 and add them as documents (make sure they still fit inside the document limit size, as Base64 strings will be larger) but I don't the see why you would do that, having GridFS that is specially designed to store files.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can I use GridFS to insert these 20 small files?

Comment: As small as you want, and you can also add metadata to it, to store info about your file. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/

Comment: Thanks a ton for your response. thats really helpful